# Using array data within an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a simple project, but I stumbled upon a problem. I have an array that looks like this:

```js
var myArray=[ 
    {          
        "Number": 23,
        "Name": "Jenny",
        "SubmissionNumber": "39",
        "photo": "photoJenny",
    },
    {          
        "Number": 3,
        "Name": "Kenny",
        "SubmissionNumber": "0",
        "photo": "photoKenny",
    },  
]
```

I want to use an if statement in order to add/remove a class to a certain div element, if the "SubmissionNumber" equals 0, but I have no idea how to do this. I tried using this, but it is not working:

```js
if ($(myArray[i].SubmissionNumber == 0)) {
  $('#submissionNumber').removeClass('submissionReceived');
}
```

Comment: What is `$()` for? ... `$(myArray[i].....`

Comment: Please attach your html file, so it would be easy to help for us.

Comment: You don't need to use the `$()`. Just use `if (myArray[i].SubmissionNumber == 0) {`

Comment: Show us html mark up, and tell us which div you are trying to modify please.

Comment: I will add it as a new answer because it is way too long for a comment

Answer (score 0):

Because you used `$(myArray[i].SubmissionNumber == 0)`. But `$` means jQuery keyword and is to select the element. `SubmissionNumber` is string. You should change the string to int and compare it with 0. So I used `parseInt` javascript function and converted the string to a integer:

```
if (parseInt(myArray[i].SubmissionNumber) == 0)) {
  $('#submissionNumber').removeClass('submissionReceived');
}
```

I changed the displayitems funciton.

```
function dislayItems(){

    for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
    
        var items = $(`<section class="items">
    
    <figure>
     <div id="submissionRec${i}" class="received">
     <i class="rec_eived">received</i>
     </div>
        <img src="imgs/`+ myArray[i].photo +`.jpg" alt="" class="rounded"/>
       <figcaption>
       <p class=name>`+ myArray[i].Name +`</p>
            <p>`+ myArray[i].Number +`</p>
            <p>`+ myArray[i].SubmissionNumber +`</p>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    `);
    $('main').append(items);

    if( parseInt(myArray[i]["SubmissionNumber"]) == 0 ) {
    
        $('#submissionRec' + i).removeClass('received');
    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you used $(myArray[i].SubmissionNumber == 0). But $ means jQuery keyword and is to select the element. currently. SubmissionNumber is string.  I should change the string to int and compare it with 0. so I used parseInt javascript function and converted the string to a integer .

Comment: Even when I remove the $ sign and use the suggested code (thank you for this btw) the class is not being removed from the div element. The class is removed for all the elements from the array, but the first one, and it is not even supposed to be removed, because the value in the array does not equal 0, but 39.

Comment: I will add it as a new answer because it is way too long for a comment

Comment: I changed the displayItems function. please check it.

Comment: It worked. THANK YOU SO MUCH. I have another question. Why did you add ${i} to the div element (<div id="submissionRec${i}" class="received">). What does it do2

Comment: ${i} means that "submissionRec"+ i.  Because id should be unique. if HTML content have same id, it's warning and html5 validation is failed. so I wanna set the unique id using index I.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you access that Javascript field value:

```
myArray[i]["SubmissionNumber"]
```

Here is the result:

[image]

EDIT: Yes, myArray[i].SubmissionNumber works too, of course.
The key problem was the jQuery $ around the conditional part.

The string approach above does bring with it a few benefits - the ability to use a variable. But either way works.

Regarding the naming of the HTML tag, he has to have the ID/NAME attribute(s) set to "SubmissionNumber".

Comment: No..there is no difference to `myArray[0].SubmissionNumber`.. But approaches are valid

Comment: I meant "both" approaches are valid